# Convert military time integer to standard time Postgres without time zone

Tags: postgresql, time

I have a time column in postgres called military_time that is an integer and in some cases needs to be padded Ex: 1400, 1300, 25, 0900. I need to convert to 2:00 pm,1:00 pm,12:25 am,9:00 am. I have read I need cast integer to time and then use the Postgres function to_char into the format I need but I am a little lost. I have found a bunch of syntax for other languages but nothing in Postgres sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be more complicated then that. You will need a way to distinguish between hour only `1400`/hour and minutes `1425` and minutes only `25`. The hour/hrs&minutes  is simple enough:

`select to_char(1400::text::time, 'HH:MI:SS AM'); 02:00:00 PM`,
`select to_char(1425::text::time, 'HH:MI:SS AM'); 02:25:00 PM`.

Minutes only could be done as:

`select to_char(('00:'|| 25::text)::time, 'HH:MI:SS AM'); 12:25:00 AM`

To pull it together:

```
create table mil_time (time_fld integer);
insert into mil_time values (1400), (1425), (25), (700);

SELECT 
    time_fld, 
    CASE 
        WHEN time_fld >= 1000 THEN 
            to_char(time_fld::text::time, 'HH:MI:SS AM') 
        WHEN time_fld >= 100 THEN 
            to_char(('0'|| time_fld::text)::time, 'HH:MI:SS AM') 
        WHEN time_fld <= 60 THEN 
            to_char(('00:'|| time_fld::text)::time, 'HH:MI:SS AM') 
        ELSE 
            '00:00:00' 
        END 
FROM 
    mil_time;

time_fld |    case     
----------+-------------
     1400 | 02:00:00 PM
     1425 | 02:25:00 PM
       25 | 12:25:00 AM
      700 | 07:00:00 AM
```

**UPDATE**

Explanation of `time_fld::text::time`. It is Postgres shorthand for cast to `text`  then to `time`, so:

`select pg_typeof(1400::text); text`

`select pg_typeof(1400::text::time);  time without time zone`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much !! can you explain this part to me time_fld::text::time

Comment: See UPDATE to answer.